# Invoke-Command -AsJob starts "running" jobs forever when too many are started

Tags: powershell

I guess there is a limit set somehwere or a limit that manifests itself when a certain (somewhat variable) number of concurrent jobs is reached.

What I am trying to do is run a small script on many servers at more or less the same time using a loop and Invoke-Command. The list of servers is an array of the result of Get-ADComputer. The loop looks like this:

```
$aComputerList | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName $_.DnsName {
        Write-Host "foo"
    }
}
```

This will create as many running jobs as there are computer accounts in $aComputerList. But the jobs will remain "running" forever. (Some jobs will fail for various explainable reasons.)

Running the same script for a subset of the computer accounts, like $aComputerList[0..40], works. The jobs will start, run for a very short time (in this example) and then terminate as expected, delivering the result ("foo").

The cut-off point appears to be around 45 because $aComputerList[0..40] always works, [0..45] usually works and [0..50] sometimes works. [0..60] never works.

Any ideas what limit I am running into? It doesn't seem to be CPU or memory.

Answer (score 0):

It could be two things - you either hit the shell's standard memory limit or it cannot handle the amount of runspaces created for the jobs. Either way, that's why there's the `-ThrottleLimit` switch for `Invoke-Command -AsJob`.